# last element in the bar plot is not showing

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I use the following code to create a bar chart in latex, but the last coordinates are not showing on the bar chart. I am not sure what I did wrong. There is no warning or what so ever there.

```
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8 \textwidth, height = 4.5cm}
\centering
\caption{Area Under the ROC Curves (AUROC) of Pandapas Network Inference by Banjo 2.2.0 and TDBN}
\label{pandapas_auroc_banjo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post,
    symbolic x coords={ i2, max50, kmeans2, q3, TDT, bikmeans3, max25, q4, i3, max75, bikmeans5, q5, kmeans3, i4, 
    mean, q2, kmeans5, i5, kmeans4, top25, bikmeans4, top75, bikmeans2, },
    xtick=data, x tick label style = {rotate=90}, ylabel= AUROC, ybar interval=.6, enlargelimits=0.18, legend pos=north east]
    \addplot [fill = green!40] coordinates {
    (i2, 0.8998)
    (max50, 0.8982)
    (kmeans2, 0.8864)
    (q3, 0.886919)
    (TDT, 0.8872)
    (bikmeans3, 0.8789)
    (max25, 0.8781)
    (q4, 0.878148)
    (i3, 0.8632)
    (max75, 0.8628)
    (bikmeans5, 0.862)
    (q5, 0.853671)
    (kmeans3, 0.852857)
    (i4, 0.85119)
    (mean, 0.8475)
    (q2, 0.846)
    (kmeans5, 0.843333)
    (i5, 0.837429)
    (kmeans4, 0.827778)
    (top25, 0.8075)
    (bikmeans4, 0.804)
    (top75, 0.7175)
    (bikmeans2, 0.495)
    };
    \legend{Banjo 2.2.0}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post,
    symbolic x coords={i2, mean, top25, max25, bikmeans2, top75, kmeans2, TDT, max50, max75, q2, },
    xtick=data, x tick label style = {rotate=90}, ylabel= AUROC,  ybar interval=.5, enlargelimits=0.15,]
    \addplot [fill = cyan!40] coordinates {
    (i2, 0.659474)
    (mean, 0.623158)
    (top25, 0.597544)
    (max25, 0.552632)
    (bikmeans2, 0.549474)
    (top75, 0.549123)
    (kmeans2, 0.500877)
    (TDT, 0.500877)
    (max50, 0.5)
    (max75, 0.5)
    (q2, 0.458246)
    };
     \legend{TDBN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

and this is what I get after compiling: 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `ybar interval` option correctly.
According to the [documentation of the pgfplots package](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) (§4.5, p.87):

> `\addplot+[ybar interval]`
>
> This plot type produces vertical bars with
>   width (and shift) relatively to intervals of coordinates. There is one
>   conceptional difference when working with intervals: an interval is
>   defined by two coordinates. Since `ybar` has one value for each
>   interval, the `i`th bar is defined by
>
> 1. the y value of the `i`th coordinates,
> 2. the x value of the `i`th coordinate as left interval boundary,
> 3. the x value of the `(i + 1)`th coordinate as right interval boundary.
>
> Consequently, **there is one coordinate too much**: the last coordinate
>   will only be used to determine the interval width; its y value doesn’t
>   influence the bar appearance.

If you want to keep the `ybar interval` plot, the obvious solution in your case is to introduce one dummy symbolic coordinate (per plot) and use it as the last coordinate, with anything as the y value.  E.g., for your second plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post,
    symbolic x coords={i2, mean, top25, max25, bikmeans2, top75,
                       kmeans2, TDT, max50, max75, q2,
                       DUMMY},
    xtick=data, x tick label style={rotate=90}, ylabel=AUROC,
    ybar interval=.5,
    enlargelimits=0.15]
    \addplot [fill = cyan!40] coordinates {
      (i2, 0.659474)
      (mean, 0.623158)
      (top25, 0.597544)
      (max25, 0.552632)
      (bikmeans2, 0.549474)
      (top75, 0.549123)
      (kmeans2, 0.500877)
      (TDT, 0.500877)
      (max50, 0.5)
      (max75, 0.5)
      (q2, 0.458246)
      (DUMMY, 0)
    };
     \legend{TDBN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to get `ybar` plots instead `ybar interval`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
\pgfplotsset{
    width=0.8 \textwidth,
    height = 4.5cm,
    %every axis plot post,
    tick pos=left,
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style = {rotate=90},
    ylabel= AUROC,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
}
\centering
\caption{Area Under the ROC Curves (AUROC) of Pandapas Network Inference by Banjo 2.2.0 and TDBN}
\label{pandapas_auroc_banjo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={ i2, max50, kmeans2, q3, TDT, bikmeans3, max25, q4, i3, max75, bikmeans5,
            q5, kmeans3, i4, mean, q2, kmeans5, i5, kmeans4, top25, bikmeans4, top75, bikmeans2, },
        ymax=1.2,
        bar width=5pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.05,
    ]
    \addplot [fill = green!40] coordinates {
    (i2, 0.8998)
    (max50, 0.8982)
    (kmeans2, 0.8864)
    (q3, 0.886919)
    (TDT, 0.8872)
    (bikmeans3, 0.8789)
    (max25, 0.8781)
    (q4, 0.878148)
    (i3, 0.8632)
    (max75, 0.8628)
    (bikmeans5, 0.862)
    (q5, 0.853671)
    (kmeans3, 0.852857)
    (i4, 0.85119)
    (mean, 0.8475)
    (q2, 0.846)
    (kmeans5, 0.843333)
    (i5, 0.837429)
    (kmeans4, 0.827778)
    (top25, 0.8075)
    (bikmeans4, 0.804)
    (top75, 0.7175)
    (bikmeans2, 0.495)
    };
    \legend{Banjo 2.2.0}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={i2, mean, top25, max25, bikmeans2, top75, kmeans2, TDT, max50, max75, q2, },
        enlarge x limits=0.1
    ]
    \addplot [fill = cyan!40] coordinates {
    (i2, 0.659474)
    (mean, 0.623158)
    (top25, 0.597544)
    (max25, 0.552632)
    (bikmeans2, 0.549474)
    (top75, 0.549123)
    (kmeans2, 0.500877)
    (TDT, 0.500877)
    (max50, 0.5)
    (max75, 0.5)
    (q2, 0.458246)
    };
     \legend{TDBN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]